# How to calculate the coefficients if I know what $F_3,f_1$ and $f_2$ are?

Tags: calculus, matrices

How to calculate the coefficients if I know what  $F_3,f_1$ and $f_2$ are?

Assume $f_3=\alpha f_1+(1-\alpha)f_2$,and $F_3=f_3f_3^H$, if now we know what are  $f_1$ ,$f_2$ and $F_3$, can we use some method to know what the $\alpha$ is?

For example,
if now $$
    f_1=\begin{bmatrix}
      0.7090 + 0.8034i\\
   0.6001 - 1.1402i\\
   0.8034 + 0.3500i\\
    \end{bmatrix}
,    f_2=\begin{bmatrix}
      0.7340 - 0.3500i\\
   0.2201 + 0.0500i\\
  -0.4060 + 0.8034i\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
$$
F_3= \begin{bmatrix}  0.5366 + 0.0000i  & 0.2220 + 0.3499i &  0.1256 - 0.4417i \\
   0.2220 - 0.3499i  & 0.3200 - 0.0000i & -0.2361 - 0.2646i \\
   0.1256 + 0.4417i & -0.2361 + 0.2646i &  0.3930 + 0.0000i \\  \end{bmatrix}$$

can we use some method to calculate what $\alpha $ is ?

Answer (score 1):

The $i^{th}$ column of $F_3$ is $$F_{3i} = f_{3i}f_3^H$$ where $f_{3i}$ is the i-th element of $f_3$. And the element $F_{3ii}$ = $f_{3i}f_{3i}^H$. So $f_{3i}$ = $e^{ai}\sqrt{F_{3ii}}$. So you get $$ f_3 = (F_{3i}/f_{3i})^H = e^{ai}F_{3i}^H/\sqrt{F_{ii}} $$  $\alpha$ and $a$ can then be solved using any two rows of the following $$ f_3 - f_2 = \alpha (f_1 - f_2) $$

Comment: $f_3$ can only be recovered up to a multiple of $e^{a \pi i}$. This is because $F_3 = (e^{a \pi i} e^{- a \pi i}) f_3 f_3^H=(e^{a \pi i} f_3) (e^{a \pi i} f_3)^H$.

Comment: I don't see the $f_3$ after doing SVD to $F_3$

Comment: @Eric so you mean $f_3=F_3 e^{\pi i} ?$

Comment: @Aniruddha Acharya I don't see the $f_3$ after doing SVD to $F_3$

Comment: @Eric so you mean we can know what is $f_3$ and $\alpha$ from $F_3$ ?

Comment: @XM551, after SVD, you get $F_3$ = $U \Sigma V^H$, where $\Sigma$ is a diagonal matrix with just one non-zero element. So you can rewrite it as a multiple of a rank-1 matrix. But Eric is right, $f_3$ can only be recovered upto multiples of $e^{a\pi i}$. Some something more is required to get $\alpha$

Comment: The $a$ in $e^{a \pi i}$ should be recoverable using the approach you proposed Aniruddha. You get $e^{a \pi i} f_3 - f_2 = \alpha (f_1 - f_2)$. You can then take real and imaginary parts two get two linear equations in two unknowns (a and $\alpha$ are the unknowns). Solve that to find $\alpha$. There are details that I didn't check carefully but I believe this works.

Comment: @Eric so now the problem is how to know the $f_3$ from the $F_3$,do you have some method to know the $f_3$,i think i don't understand  what you mean,can you explain more in detail?

Comment: $F_3$ is a rank one matrix, so it has exactly one singular vector (or eigenvector) for its nonzero singular (eigen) value. Since $F_3$ is self-adjoint we can use an eigendecomposition over an SVD, and I think theoretically its a bit easier to understand. It should be reasonably straight forward to prove that $f_3$ is an eigenvector of $F_3$ and it corresponds to the eigenvalue $|f_3|^2$. Futhermore, all other eigenvalues of $F_3$ are zero (you can check that any vector orthogonal to $f_3$ is in the null space of $F_3$).

Comment: Thanks, Eric. XM551, I think there is an easier way to get $f_3$ from $F_3$. Let me update the answer.

Comment: This means that if you compute an eigenvector $v$ for the nonzero eigenvalue of $F_3$ then $v$ is a constant multiple of $f_3$. Furthermore, if you normalize so that $v$ has norm $1$ then $|f_3| v$ is equal to $e^{a i \pi} f_3$ for some real $a$. Recall that you can get $|f_3|^2$ by finding the nonzero eigenvalue of $F_3$.

Comment: thanks you two,now i understand,but i want to ask $f_{3i}=e^{ai}\sqrt{F_{3ii}}$,why is $e^{ai}$,but not the other number?

Comment: All the complex numbers $z = e^{ai}\sqrt{F_{3ii}}$ satisfy $zz^H = F_{3ii}$. So the possibility of $a\neq0$ should also be considered while finding $f_3$...